# Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return filter.filters }" Message: filter is not defined

Tags: knockout.js, foreach

I am getting the following error message when running knockout code in my view model:

**Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return filter.filters }" Message: filter is not defined**

When calling my page I want to be able to call MakePageModel to be able to load data from my model.  The model is working.

Any help you can give me would be great.

**strong text**

```
window.makeApp.makeViewModel = (function (ko, datacontext) {

   MakePageModel = function (datacontext) {
            if (!datacontext) {
                datacontext = {};
        }

        **//Load data to filter, sort and page on**
        var self = this;
        self.makes = ExtractModels(self, makeLists.getMakeLists, makeList);

        var filters = [
            {
                Type: "text",
                Name: "Name",
                Value: ko.observable(""),
                RecordValue: function (record) { return record.name; }
            },
            {
                Type: "select",
                Name: "Status",
                Options: [
                    GetOption("All", "All", null),
                    GetOption("None", "None", "None"),
                    GetOption("New", "New", "New"),
                    GetOption("Recently Modified", "Recently Modified", "Recently Modified")
                ],
                CurrentOption: ko.observable(),
                RecordValue: function (record) { return record.status; }
            }
        ];
        var sortOptions = [
            {
                Name: "ID",
                Value: "ID",
                Sort: function (left, right) { return left.id < right.id; }
            },
            {
                Name: "Name",
                Value: "Name",
                Sort: function (left, right) { return CompareCaseInsensitive(left.name, right.name); }
            },
            {
                Name: "Status",
                Value: "Status",
                Sort: function (left, right) { return CompareCaseInsensitive(left.status, right.status); }
            }
        ];
        self.filter = new FilterModel(filters, self.makes);
        self.sorter = new SorterModel(sortOptions, self.filter.filteredRecords);
        self.pager = new PagerModel(self.sorter.orderedRecords);
    },

    more code..............

})(ko, makeApp.datacontext);

 // Initiate the Knockout bindings
ko.applyBindings(window.makeApp.makeViewModel);
```

**HTML Code**

```
<div data-bind="foreach: filter.filters">
    <div>
      <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>:<br />
    </div>
    <div data-bind="if: Type == 'select'">
    <select data-bind="options: Options, optionsText: 'Name', value: CurrentOption">       </select>
</div>
                <div data-bind="if: Type == 'text'">
                    <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

---

Thanks.  Yes I needed to add my ko.observables.  I am still getting the same error message.

Here's my viewmodel.

```
window.makeApp.makeViewModel = (function (ko, datacontext) {

//Data
var self = this;
self.makeLists = ko.observableArray();
self.error = ko.observable();

//Operations
//Load initial state from the server, convert it to make instances, then populate self

function MakePageModel(datacontext) {
        if (!datacontext) {
            datacontext = {};
    }

    //var self = this;
    //self.makes = ExtractModels(self, makeLists, makeList);

    var filters = [
        {
            Type: "text",
            Name: "Name",
            Value: ko.observable(""),
            RecordValue: function (record) { return record.name; }
        },
        {
            Type: "select",
            Name: "Status",
            Options: [
                GetOption("All", "All", null),
                GetOption("None", "None", "None"),
                GetOption("New", "New", "New"),
                GetOption("Recently Modified", "Recently Modified", "Recently Modified")
            ],
            CurrentOption: ko.observable(),
            RecordValue: function (record) { return record.status; }
        }
    ];
    var sortOptions = [
        {
            Name: "ID",
            Value: "ID",
            Sort: function (left, right) { return left.id < right.id; }
        },
        {
            Name: "Name",
            Value: "Name",
            Sort: function (left, right) { return CompareCaseInsensitive(left.name, right.name); }
        },
        {
            Name: "Status",
            Value: "Status",
            Sort: function (left, right) { return CompareCaseInsensitive(left.status, right.status); }
        }
    ];
    self.filter = new FilterModel(filters, self.makeLists);
    self.sorter = new SorterModel(sortOptions, self.filter.filteredRecords);
    self.pager = new PagerModel(self.sorter.orderedRecords);
}

function PagerModel(records) {
     var self = this;
     self.pageSizeOptions = ko.observableArray([1, 5, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500]);

     self.records = GetObservableArray(records);
     self.currentPageIndex = ko.observable(self.records().length > 0 ? 0 : -1);
     self.currentPageSize = ko.observable(25);
     self.recordCount = ko.computed(function () {
         return self.records().length;
     });
     self.maxPageIndex = ko.computed(function () {
         return Math.ceil(self.records().length / self.currentPageSize()) - 1;
     });
     self.currentPageRecords = ko.computed(function () {
         var newPageIndex = -1;
         var pageIndex = self.currentPageIndex();
         var maxPageIndex = self.maxPageIndex();
         if (pageIndex > maxPageIndex) {
             newPageIndex = maxPageIndex;
         }
         else if (pageIndex == -1) {
             if (maxPageIndex > -1) {
                 newPageIndex = 0;
             }
             else {
                 newPageIndex = -2;
             }
         }
         else {
             newPageIndex = pageIndex;
         }

         if (newPageIndex != pageIndex) {
             if (newPageIndex >= -1) {
                 self.currentPageIndex(newPageIndex);
             }

             return [];
         }

         var pageSize = self.currentPageSize();
         var startIndex = pageIndex * pageSize;
         var endIndex = startIndex + pageSize;
         return self.records().slice(startIndex, endIndex);
     }).extend({ throttle: 5 });
     self.moveFirst = function () {
         self.changePageIndex(0);
     };
     self.movePrevious = function () {
         self.changePageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() - 1);
     };
     self.moveNext = function () {
         self.changePageIndex(self.currentPageIndex() + 1);
     };
     self.moveLast = function () {
         self.changePageIndex(self.maxPageIndex());
     };
     self.changePageIndex = function (newIndex) {
         if (newIndex < 0
             || newIndex == self.currentPageIndex()
             || newIndex > self.maxPageIndex()) {
             return;
         }

         self.currentPageIndex(newIndex);
     };
     self.onPageSizeChange = function () {
         self.currentPageIndex(0);
     };
     self.renderPagers = function () {
         var pager = "<div><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.moveFirst, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() > 0\">&lt;&lt;</a><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.movePrevious, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() > 0\">&lt;</a>Page <span data-bind=\"text: pager.currentPageIndex() + 1\"></span> of <span data-bind=\"text: pager.maxPageIndex() + 1\"></span> [<span data-bind=\"text: pager.recordCount\"></span> Record(s)]<select data-bind=\"options: pager.pageSizeOptions, value: pager.currentPageSize, event: { change: pager.onPageSizeChange }\"></select><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.moveNext, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() < pager.maxPageIndex()\">&gt;</a><a href=\"#\" data-bind=\"click: pager.moveLast, enable: pager.currentPageIndex() < pager.maxPageIndex()\">&gt;&gt;</a></div>";
         $("div.Pager").html(pager);
     };
     self.renderNoRecords = function () {
         var message = "<span data-bind=\"visible: pager.recordCount() == 0\">No records found.</span>";
         $("div.NoRecords").html(message);
     };

     self.renderPagers();
     self.renderNoRecords();
 }

function SorterModel(sortOptions, records) {
     var self = this;
     self.records = GetObservableArray(records);
     self.sortOptions = ko.observableArray(sortOptions);
     self.sortDirections = ko.observableArray([
         {
             Name: "Asc",
             Value: "Asc",
             Sort: false
         },
         {
             Name: "Desc",
             Value: "Desc",
             Sort: true
         }]);
     self.currentSortOption = ko.observable(self.sortOptions()[0]);
     self.currentSortDirection = ko.observable(self.sortDirections()[0]);
     self.orderedRecords = ko.computed(function () {
         var records = self.records();
         var sortOption = self.currentSortOption();
         var sortDirection = self.currentSortDirection();
         if (sortOption == null || sortDirection == null) {
             return records;
         }

         var sortedRecords = records.slice(0, records.length);
         SortArray(sortedRecords, sortDirection.Sort, sortOption.Sort);
         return sortedRecords;
     }).extend({ throttle: 5 });
 }

function FilterModel(filters, records) {
     var self = this;
     self.records = GetObservableArray(records);
     self.filters = ko.observableArray(filters);
     self.activeFilters = ko.computed(function () {
         var filters = self.filters();
         var activeFilters = [];
         for (var index = 0; index < filters.length; index++) {
             var filter = filters[index];
             if (filter.CurrentOption) {
                 var filterOption = filter.CurrentOption();
                 if (filterOption && filterOption.FilterValue != null) {
                     var activeFilter = {
                         Filter: filter,
                         IsFiltered: function (filter, record) {
                             var filterOption = filter.CurrentOption();
                             if (!filterOption) {
                                 return;
                             }

                             var recordValue = filter.RecordValue(record);
                             return recordValue != filterOption.FilterValue; NoMat
                         }
                     };
                     activeFilters.push(activeFilter);
                 }
             }
             else if (filter.Value) {
                 var filterValue = filter.Value();
                 if (filterValue && filterValue != "") {
                     var activeFilter = {
                         Filter: filter,
                         IsFiltered: function (filter, record) {
                             var filterValue = filter.Value();
                             filterValue = filterValue.toUpperCase();

                             var recordValue = filter.RecordValue(record);
                             recordValue = recordValue.toUpperCase();
                             return recordValue.indexOf(filterValue) == -1;
                         }
                     };
                     activeFilters.push(activeFilter);
                 }
             }
         }

         return activeFilters;
     });
     self.filteredRecords = ko.computed(function () {
         var records = self.records();
         var filters = self.activeFilters();
         if (filters.length == 0) {
             return records;
         }

         var filteredRecords = [];
         for (var rIndex = 0; rIndex < records.length; rIndex++) {
             var isIncluded = true;
             var record = records[rIndex];
             for (var fIndex = 0; fIndex < filters.length; fIndex++) {
                 var filter = filters[fIndex];
                 var isFiltered = filter.IsFiltered(filter.Filter, record);
                 if (isFiltered) {
                     isIncluded = false;
                     break;
                 }
             }

             if (isIncluded) {
                 filteredRecords.push(record);
             }
         }

         return filteredRecords;
     }).extend({ throttle: 200 });
 }

function ExtractModels(parent, data, constructor) {
     var models = [];
     if (data == null) {
         return models;
     }

     for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
         var row = data[index];
         var model = new constructor(row, parent);
         models.push(model);
     }

     return models;
 }

function GetObservableArray(array) {
    if (typeof (array) == 'function') {
        return array;
    }

    return ko.observableArray(array);
}

function CompareCaseInsensitive(left, right) {
    if (left == null) {
        return right == null;
    }
    else if (right == null) {
        return false;
    }

    return left.toUpperCase() <= right.toUpperCase();
}

function GetOption(name, value, filterValue) {
    var option = {
        Name: name,
        Value: value,
        FilterValue: filterValue
    };
    return option;
}

function SortArray(array, direction, comparison) {
    if (array == null) {
        return [];
    }

    for (var oIndex = 0; oIndex < array.length; oIndex++) {
        var oItem = array[oIndex];
        for (var iIndex = oIndex + 1; iIndex < array.length; iIndex++) {
            var iItem = array[iIndex];
            var isOrdered = comparison(oItem, iItem);
            if (isOrdered == direction) {
                array[iIndex] = oItem;
                array[oIndex] = iItem;
                oItem = iItem;
            }
        }
    }

    return array;
}

datacontext.getMakeLists(makeLists, error); // load update makes 

return {
    makeLists: self.makeLists,
    error: self.error
};
})(ko, makeApp.datacontext);

 // Initiate the Knockout bindings
ko.applyBindings(makeApp.makeViewModel);
```

Here's my html:

```
<tr>
    <td class="LsSearch">

        <b>Filters:</b><br />

        <div class="" data-bind="foreach: filter.filters">
            <div>
                <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>:<br />
            </div>
            <div data-bind="if: Type == 'select'">
                <select data-bind="options: Options, optionsText: 'Name', value: CurrentOption"></select>
            </div>
            <div data-bind="if: Type == 'text'">
                <input type="text" data-bind="value: Value, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <b>Sorts:</b>
        Field:
        <br />
        <select data-bind="options: sorter.sortOptions, optionsText: 'Name', value: sorter.currentSortOption"></select>
        Direction:
        <select data-bind="options: sorter.sortDirections, optionsText: 'Name', value: sorter.currentSortDirection"></select>
        <br />
        <br />

         <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Account ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
             <tbody data-bind="foreach: pager.currentPageRecords">
                 <tr>
                     <td>
                         <span data-bind="text: id"></span>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <span data-bind="text: accountId"></span>
                     </td>

                     <td>
                         <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                     </td>
                     <td>
                         <span data-bind="text: description"></span>
                     </td>

                 </tr>
             </tbody>
        </table>


    </td>
```

Comment: can you show FilterModel method?

Comment: Yes. I have add the FilterModel method.

Comment: I would suggest to drill down your example, so the same occurs in a much smaller code base. And then provide a jsFiddle of that. You might solve the issue yourself in the process. And otherwise someone can look at the problem. But with the current amount of code, this requires too much work to read into, at least for me :).
I managed to solve an issue with the exact same error message by adding the `$data.` prefix as described [here](http://www.knockmeout.net/2013/06/knockout-debugging-strategies-plugin.html). But in my case an (optional) property was missing, might be different in yours.

Comment: Why don't you simplify your question, remove all the unimportant parts of code and HTML to make it easy to read, understand and answer? There are lots of superfluous bits of code nad HTML.

Answer (score 0):

none of the variables you have is defined as ko.observable. you should use  [ko mapping](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) in order to tranaform your model into a view model. maybe you've done it in the constractors you're not showing in the code, but this is one of the things that will throw the exception you've got

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this question, and it was because the second param was null of `ko.applyBindings(viewModel, jsObject)`, you can try to test it.